# MapReduce Application Master using complete node, no other task running on that node

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

I have deployed 6 node (1 Master and 5 Slaves) hadoop cluster on amazon ec2 by using T2.Medium instances( each instance have 4 Gb ram and two virtual cores). In the yarn-site.xml,I have added these two properties:

```
<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
<value>3072</value> 
</property>
```

This allows nodemanager to use maximum of 3 GB ram on each node. Leaving 1 Gb ram for the system.

```
<property>
<name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb</name>
<value>1536</value>
</property>
```

And this gives minimum ram to be used by each container. I have used these properties so that maximum of two containers will run parallely on each node.

But When I run the program, the slave node on which Mapreduce Application Master is running (MRAppMaster), there is no other task (container running). Although ram used by the Application Master is only about 10% of total (i.e 400-500 Mb).
 Whereas on other slave nodes, each node have two containers running. This degrades the performance. Because the program is compute intensive, and all the processing power of node where Application Master is running, is unused( as Application Master only use about 0-1 % of processing power).

Ideally, there should also be one container running on the node where 
MRAppMaster is running.

So can anyone please help me regarding this.